NE-77 neon glow bulb trigger electrode as signal source?
The NE-77 neon glow lamp is like the NE-2 externally but has a third electrode intermediate "trigger" electrode between the power electrodes.

The trigger electrode triggers the plasma by being temporarily shorted to one of the power electrodes.  It operates like a tiny Krytron.
Once the plasma is established, under what conditions, if any, would radio waves passing through the plasma produce changes in the voltage on the trigger electrode?  How would one estimate the magnitude of such a signal?
One reason to believe there might be signal present on the trigger electrode (other than that produced by the electrodes as metal antenna elements) is analogous to the Hall Effect:

Above image from: "Hall Effect Sensor" by ElectronicsTutorials
Consider an RF source from a Tx polarized vertically, and the Rx NE-77 oriented such that its metal leads are aligned vertically . Maximal signal is picked up by the metal leads.  Now consider the plasma current in the direction of the oncoming RF.  At maximum magnetic field, the crossing electron velocity vector exhibits the qv x B Lorentz force that moves the electrons at a right angle to the trigger electrode.  This is similar to what happens in the Hall Effect sensor pictured above.  However, the positively charged ions are at least 1000 times more massive than their electrons.  Their Lorentz force is 1000 times smaller and must push a mass that is 1000 times larger. The positive charges will remain near the trigger electrode.  The bipolar charge separation that occurs in a Hall Voltage will, instead be uni-polar -- going from neutral potential to a positive potential.  The magnetic field swings back and forth causing the electrons to swing from side to side of the trigger electrode.  This uni-polar swing would be a rectified version of the incoming RF frequency, hence one would expect about twice the frequency to RF appear on the trigger lead.
The length of the metal leads being only a few mm long, one might thing the resulting signal strength from the quasi-Hall effect could be larger.
Although this may or may not be a practical plasma antenna, there may be other uses for such a sensor.

"The bipolar charge separation that occurs in a Hall Voltage will, instead be uni-polar" -- this claim has been invented out of whole cloth, nor does it follow from the proceeding sentences.

I would have to do some tests to be sure, but I suspect that, as the inter-electrode space becomes ionized, all three electrodes remain conductive to each other, give or take the voltage drop to electrodes (corresponding to dark-space potentials).  How conductive, depends on the degree of ionization, i.e. the bias current between the main driven electrodes.
Certainly, raising or lowering the remaining electrode's voltage above or below the other(s) will cause it to behave as the main current flow path instead, but the interesting question is what lies between those voltage extremes, in terms of V(I) curve, and dynamic resistance.  This suggests a means of characterizing the device, which might be of particular interest as the manufacturer has not provided such detail.
Radio waves, at least at low amplitude, will simply be passed or attenuated according to the mutual resistance between electrodes.  Whether this is positive or negative, depends on the frequency, recombination rate, and glow parameters generally (pressure, gas, spacing, etc.).  (A glow discharge could indeed be used as a crude negative-resistance amplifier, though this is most likely only applicable at quite low frequencies, <100kHz for neon tubes in my experience.)
Waves of high amplitude, at frequencies higher than the recombination frequency, can excite the plasma directly through its resistance, inducing more ionization, reducing resistance further; the result is an averaged-amplitude-dependent (but not instantaneous voltage or current-dependent) nonlinear resistance.
In this way, a glow lamp could perhaps be used as a sort of PIN diode, for switching RF, while also being dependent on RF itself; this may help or hinder an application, but in any case one must be aware of this behavior in order to design with it.
What effect absorbed RF has on the remaining electrode's V(I) curve, you would also have to characterize.
The glow is no larger than the lamp itself, so has no value as an antenna.  Or, if you prefer: the antenna value of the component as a whole, regardless of operating condition, is nothing more than its lead length.

Vertically polarized EM encountering horizontal leads would provide less signal than vertically oriented leads. The electron velocity field's cross product with the incoming magnetic field of the RF would tend to remove negative charges from the vicinity of the trigger electrode.  So wouldn't this produce voltage frequency a factor of 2 higher than the RF on the trigger lead since the ions would barely move but the electron field vary from side to side?  Thanks for the thoughtful response.

...A what? Electron velocity field? "Voltage frequency"? What RF? you haven't defined any boundary conditions or operating parameters.

I had an incorrect idea about the polarization but I hope my edit to the question clarifies the rest of my comment.

If all three leads pick up the same induced voltage, the total RF across the tube diffs to near zero. Hall effect is symmetrical and linear, meaning magnitude is proportional to field direction; no rectification effect will occur. Electron drift over an RF cycle (<µs?) will be approximately negligible anyway; or for frequencies or field strengths great enough to show a significant effect, induction into the plasma heats it up more than any signal goes up the leads (at which frequencies the leads will have high impedance i.e. microwaves)

I doubt there is any measurable effect (and probably noise from the discharge will limit what is measurable). I also don't see any deliberate asymmetry analogous to the Hall sensor.
I would expect the middle electrode to have a voltage roughly midway between the two electrodes when the lamp is  in normal operation.
GE in their seminal 1965 Neon bulb manual says.

ELECTROSTATIC FIELDS
Electrostatic fields noticeably affect glow lamps. For example, if the
voltage across the lamp is held below the static breakdown voltage,
the appearance of an electrostatic field in proximity to the lamp can
cause it to start. If the dark enclosure is a conductive shield, its
polarity in relation to the lamp cathode will determine the direction
in which the breakdown voltage changes. If the shield is of the same
polarity as the lamp anode the dark starting voltage will be reduced
somewhat. If at cathode polarity, the breakdown voltage will increase.
This same effect can be achieved by mounting a conductor in the
immediate vicinity of the lamp's electrodes and connecting it to the
anode or cathode lead. No similar effect has been observed for
magnetic fields.
The changes in breakdown voltage due to the foregoing conditions are
pronounced when the lamp is in total darkness, but have negligible
effect when the lamp is in normal, ambient illumination. Electrostatic
fields have no noticeable effect upon the maintaining voltage

Since (when conducting) there's no "no noticeable effect" from electric fields and "no .. effect" from magnetic fields, then ordinary levels of radio signals should have no measurable effect. Of course large amounts of microwave radiation can actually cause the bulb to light without an external connections, so you might expect measurable effects in extreme conditions, even if it is normally operating. It would be difficult to separate those effects from the RF you'd pick up with a cm or so of wire though. The discharge itself has a kind of inductive effect with current lagging voltage in the low audio range, which does not bode well for interesting behavior at  even low RF frequencies.
